# Forward Chaining First Order Logic (Unification)

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence, substitution, unification, unify

I'm studying for my final exam and I'm having trouble understanding this FC algorithm:

[image]

I understand it up to the part where you standardize each rule.  Then I think the next line is saying for each theta that satisfied the Generalized Modus Ponens (p'_i*Theta = p_i*Theta), do... something.  What is that something?  I don't really understand what is happening after that part.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `Theta` is a substitution that can make some set of terms you know to be true (the `p'`s in the `KB`) equal to the `p`s in the rule, then you can conclude that `q'` (`q` with the same `Theta` applied to it) is also true.  If that `q'` isn't already known, then it goes into `new`; if it unifies w/ our query, then we've succeeded.

Comment: Suppose `King(John)` is already known. We'll then reach `q' = King(y)`. This new fact unifies with `King(John)` via `{y/John}`, so it won't be added to the database. But it was a totally new fact. So the algorithm seems broken.